# How to extract json response url with dynamic file using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to extract json response from my server which is {"fileUrl":"https://example.com/reports/985ed46a-416d-4653-b63d-abaee55563d5.zip} and what I just want to get is zip file which I want to download via jmeter for load testing.the file is dynamic and want to use this as variable to be used by another http request in jmeter.

Comment: If you need to extract Json path from response, Json Extractor is used. Then by passing the extracted variable to the http request sample and by adding Save Response data to a file Listener, you can download the file to Jmeter/bin path.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which will download the .zip file and put `${fileUrl}` JMeter Variable into "Path" field:

   [image]
4. That's it, your second HTTP Request should download the file:

   [image]

   if you need to store it to the file system you can use [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener